# How to debug HTTP Proxy problems with artifactory?

Tags: maven-2, proxy, http-proxy, artifactory

I have an artifactory within a corporate network. I configured a http proxy for each remote repository. It doesn't work. How could I possibly find out why it doesn't work? Are there any log settings which I could tweak?

Using the same proxy within Firefox works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifactory 2 uses [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) for logging, you can find its configuration in $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/logback.xml

If you can access the repository through the browser, it's likely the problem is in your Maven configuration. If you've a [proxy configuration](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) defined, you'll need to ensure the proxy is set to exclude your internal http proxy server.

If you run Maven with the -X switch, it will give you more details on the connection attempts Maven is making.

Comment: What do you mean by "you'll need to ensure the proxy is set to exclude your internal http proxy server" and how can I check that? Thanks!