# Configure Artifactory to proxy Remote Repository via Proxy

Tags: artifactory, http-proxy

First I created a proxy configuration in Artifactory with required host IP and port then I configured for the maven remote repo:

```
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
```

I selected "maven" for package type, "maven-2-default" for repository layout and remote layout mapping, selected the proxy key (Artifactory identifier) under the network tab. But clicking "test" yields:

```
Connection failed: Error 403: Forbidden (on a popup window, no logging)
```

That is, no information appears in the Artifactory logs when using the "test" connection button; however, the 403 connection failed error always pops up with the button.

On a browser, an error is logged when navigating to:

```
https://{private name}/artifactory/list/{artifactory name for proxy repo}/
```

The error is:

```
{date time} [http-nio-8085-exec-5] [INFO ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:940) - Error listing remote resources http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/: Unable to retrieve http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/: 403: Forbidden (remote response: 403: Forbidden)
```

The server.xml file for Catalina shows that a connection is setup with port 8085, redirect 8443, UTF-8, and as shown above the default protocol is http nio.

Performing the following operation from the Artifactory server works fine and returns the html page, index of maven 2.

```
curl -x {proxy IP}:{proxy port} http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
```

Without Artifactory, maven command-line, lifecycle operations work using the proxy. The proxy and an active profile configuration with the repository url info were added to the maven settings.xml file.

LDAP settings in Artifactory appear to be working fine. The test button for the ldap settings yield "Successfully connected and authenticated the test user."

The permissions settings are set to allow manage for the account connected via the Artifactory UI.

There are other, similar questions but a relevant solution to this problem is not discussed:

[Maven Github repository + Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350753/maven-github-repository-artifactory)

[How to debug HTTP Proxy problems with artifactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289402/how-to-debug-http-proxy-problems-with-artifactory?rq=1)

Comment: Does it work as a repository (disregard the test button for a second)? Can you retrieve artifacts from it?

Comment: On an unrelated matter, why would you want to add maven central to Artifactory? Is JCenter blocked in your environment?

Comment: Regarding first comment: Not known. First test was direct to the source repo and not via Artifactory. Will configure and test.  Regarding second comment, will be using JCenter.

Comment: If you are planning to use JCenter, why do you need to configure repo1? JCenter is a superset and has everything you need and more.

Comment: Will not be using repo1 (maven central).  I tried several repos just to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Maven central is not blocked via browser. JCenter is blocked via browser. Both yield the same negative response as above (403: Forbidden) when testing configuration in Artifactory.

Comment: I Requested information from network team to understand if the repositories are blocked.

Comment: Looks like something with you proxy config - can you post the configuration you created?   also as you stated it might be something that your corp network actively blocks

Comment: I described the config of host, port. I did not set user credentials or nt section nor entered host in the redirecting target section.  I checked the firewall on the Artifactory server and the connectivity between servers with nmap -sT -O {ip}. The Artifactory ports were open (listening) from a remote server.